# MongoDB Mongoose schema design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema design question.  I have a UserSchema and a PostSchema.

```
var User = new Schema({
  name: String
});

var Post = new Schema({
 user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId } 
});
```

Also, user is able to follow other users. Post can be liked by other users.
I would like to query User's followers and User's following, with mongoose features such as limit, skip, sort, etc.  I also want to query Post that a user likes.

Basically, my only attempt of solving this is to keep double reference in each schema.  The schemas become

```
var User = new Schema({
  name: String,
  followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
});

var Post = new Schema({
 creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
 userLikes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
});
```

so, the code that will be used to query

```
// Find posts that I create
Post.find({creator: myId}, function(err, post) { ... });

// Find posts that I like
Post.find({userLikes: myId}, function(err, post) { ... });

// Find users that I follow
User.find({followers: myId}, function(err, user) { ... });

// Find users that follow me
User.find({following: myId}, function(err, user) { ... });
```

Is there a way other than doing double reference like this that seems error prone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actally, you don't need the double reference. Let's assume you keep the `following` reference.

```
var User = new Schema({
  name: String,
  following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
});
```

You can use `.populate()` to get the users you're following:

**EDIT: added skip/limit options to show example for pagination**

```
User.findById(myId).populate({ path:'following', options: { skip: 20, limit: 10 } }).exec(function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    // handle err
  }
  if (user) {
     // user.following[] <-- contains a populated array of users you're following
  }
});
```

And, as you've already mentioned ...

```
User.find({following: myId}).exec(function(err, users) { ... });
```

... retrieves the users that are following you.

Comment: Yes I can use populate.  However, imagine if I have a lot of users. Then if I populate that, and send those to the front end, it will be a lot of data.  I am thinking of more on how to implement pagination / infinite scrolling.

Comment: You should have stated so in your original question. You can't expect a solution that fits your needs if you don't specify your needs. That said, there's no reason you can't implement a pagination/infinite scrolling solution using the answer above as your starti point. How to implement such a solution, however, is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. How do I implement pagination using your solution? Because on standard query, I can just do limit and skip, but with populate, there is no such option.

Comment: `.populate()` has `skip` and `limit` options you can use to implement paging. I will update my answer.